# How to set alarm 3 times a day?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I want to make a program that calls an intent in a specific time, at 8 o'clock for breakfast, 1 o'clock for lunch, and half past six for dinner for every day.

How can I do that? This is because if I use `AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY / 3`, it cannot give the specific time.

Or is there any other class that I can use ?

Here's my code:

```
package com.makansehat;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.*;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
// import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * @author Prabu
 */
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void startAlert(View view) {
        Calendar skr = Calendar.getInstance();

        pagi.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
        pagi.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 53);

        Calendar siang = Calendar.getInstance();

        siang.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
        siang.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 55);

        Calendar malam = Calendar.getInstance();

        malam.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
        malam.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);

        // EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.time);
        // int i = Integer.parseInt(text.getText().toString());

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, pagi.getTimeInMillis(), siang.getTimeInMillis(), pi);

    }

}
```

Comment: How does your code even compile? I noticed you declared `skr` but used `pagi` for calendar instance, `pagi` should throw a syntax error when compiling.

Comment: upps..my mistake, yups already fixed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create 3 alarms:

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, pagi.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);

alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, siang.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);

alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, malam.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here i attach Code to Wake up the device to fire the alarm at precisely 8:30 a.m., and every 20 minutes thereafter:

```
private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
private PendingIntent alarmIntent;
...
alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

// Set the alarm to start at 8:30 a.m.
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);

// setRepeating() lets you specify a precise custom interval--in this case,
// 20 minutes.
alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
        1000 * 60 * 20, alarmIntent);
```

I hope you will understand what can i say just set your first time to calander and there after give interval manually using for loop for example:
Here timelist is your second,third etc time interval miniutes for trigger alarm

```
for(int i=0;i<timelist.size();i++){

      alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            timelist[i], alarmIntent);
   }
```

Or Second Way to do your Task Take three alarm manager and set your time thats it.

hope it will help you...